# Is it possible to plot a chart in python where both the x axis and y axis are categorical?

Tags: python, plot, data-visualization, categorical-data

I would like to make a bubble chart out of this dataframe that shows gaps or frequencies of missing values in data analysis.

Is it possible to list field names or categorical values on the x axis and the plot the number of missing by different locations on the y axis?

Or do I need to create subplots for each location?

```
                 |Targeted Start Date  |Targeted End Date  |Projected End Date  
Location         | ------------------- | ----------------- | -----------------                    
Q                |                  0  |                0  |                 0   
R                |                  6  |                7  |               113   
V                |                  1  |                1  |                 6   
Z                |                  0  |                0  |                 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d1 = {'Location': ['Q', 'R', 'V', 'Z'], 'Targeted Start Date': [0, 6, 1 ,0], 'Targeted End Date': [0, 7, 1 ,0], 'Targeted End Date': [0, 113, 6 ,0]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d1)

#df = df.set_index('Location')

print(df)

dfMelt = df.melt(id_vars='Location', value_name='MissingItemCnt', var_name='FieldName')

print(dfMelt)

alt.Chart(dfMelt).mark_point().encode(x = 'FieldName', y = 'Location', size = 'MissingItemCnt')
```

[image]